# How to get next colse date according to working days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

| id | workings_days(day of the week) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "1,5" |
| 2 | "2,3" |

**output will be**

| id | workings_days(day of the week) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

and then find close next date from current date according to working days

`for example :`  
if working days 1(means monday) , 5(means friday)
and current day is 3 (means wednesday) 
then nxt close day is 5 means friday

Comment: What have you tried? I think you should use phps explode-operator to split the workings_days string. I don't know a similar funktion in sql to do the split.

Comment: can i slove this using sql ?